# Spring Batch: How to implement a many-to-one ItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a very large set of spreadsheets that need to be generated using spring batch.

I have an ItemReader emitting "Rows", and I would like my ItemProcessor to emit 1 "Sheet" for every 3000 Rows it receives.

Is there any way to specify this many-to-one processing relationship to spring?

Comment: For this sort of job, I've always looked at converting to csv's. I've used stuff  like:
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv
This can be done quite easily in the spring framework ... google is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a "many-to-one ItemProcessor" that you need. You can use a chunk oriented step with a chunk size of 3000 (this should be ok) with an item writer that writes a sheet per chunk.